# Sendmail() takes a long time to execute

Tags: php, cakephp, smtp, sendmail, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using sendmail from PHP (CakePHP 1.3) on a Linux Server (Ubuntu 10.10), and it's taking forever to execute, but eventually goes through. SMTP is running as a daemon -- for a while, I thought the problem was that it had to start the process on each send().

I am a bit of a novice when it comes to server configuration, so any help is appreciated.

Here is my application code, for reference:

```
            $this->Email->from    = 'Hello <hello@example.com>';
            $this->Email->to      = 'Hello <hello@example.com>';
            $this->Email->subject = 'Hello';
            $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
            $this->Email->template = 'my_template';
            $this->data['Inquiry']['id']= $this->Inquiry->id;
            $this->set('inquiry', $this->data['Inquiry']);
            $this->Email->send();
```

Comment: Perhaps there are any pointers in your mail log file?

Comment: General knowledge: It's considered best practice to use a consistent naming convention, all variable, property, function and method names should be lowercase, multiple words can be named either with_underscores_each, or withCamelCase. Only class names should have the first letter uppercase.

Comment: If the mail actually gets delivered, then it may be that your smtp/sendmail deamon pools the mails and sends them at a curtain interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, of course, I found the solution myself immediately after posting the question.

I omitted this essential line from my code:

`$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';`

Hope this is useful to others!

Comment: also you forgot to mention the version you are using - you should know by now that this is crucial in order to provide adequate help.

Comment: I had similar problem, but code a bit different. `mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers, '-finfo@domain.com', $delivery);`